# WordPress products authentication

Tags: plugins

Is there any plugins or any option available in WordPress 5.0.3 for check authentication of products quality. 
I'm selling online medicine so prevent any local (duplicate) products. We put scratch card within box, buyer will scratch a card and number will appear then buyer wi open our website and submit number then a message will appear "thanks for buy this a genuine product" or any context could be. So this is the process, any plugins or anything else possible for do this..

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of anything sorry but that wouldn't be that hard to do: load all of the scratch card codes into a table and have a page that checks if a number is in the table and then either cancels it or attaches it to a customer's order number or login so that someone else can't duplicate the code. However I don't understand the process: they place an order with you, and you ship the order, so at what point can a bad actor switch out the medicine for counterfeit in a way they wouldn't also get the scratch card? And why does verification on your website help?

Comment: Actually we selling online and offline too. This facility is  for offline customer.